# how can I send an email from codeigniter application using exim?

Tags: codeigniter, postfix-mta, exim

All contact forms that i have created on old server worked just fine. On the newone Postfix is not installed, they use Exim and i have to re-work all my contact forms.

Anyone know how can i send e-mail from codeigniter using Exim?

Regards,Zoran

Answer (score 0):

Not able to find a reference to CodeIgniter, but the link below is helpful for PHP, maybe you can check if it works for CodeIgniter as well.

http://www.pagefabric.com/blogs/2012/02/19/how-to-fix-php-not-sending-mail-in-debian-6-and-exim4/